# Angular : ERROR SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Holla, I've a problem on the response of every submitted data. I've checked on the routing, etc but I couldn't snap which was the wrong syntax is.

Here are the routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'customer', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},
  { path: 'customer', loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerPageModule' },
  { path: 'addcustomer', loadChildren: './addcustomer/addcustomer.module#AddcustomerPageModule' },
  { path: 'addcustomer/:id/:name/:desc', loadChildren: './addcustomer/addcustomer.module#AddcustomerPageModule' },
  { path: 'show', loadChildren: './show/show.module#ShowPageModule' },
];
```

the class :

```
this.postPvdr.postData(body, 'proses-api.php').subscribe(data => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/customer');
        console.log('OK');
```

I've tried to change the route from `this.router.navigate(['/customer']);` to

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/customer');
```

But, none of it worked.

here are the proses-api.php

> ```
>         include "library/config.php";
>
>         $postjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
>         $today    = date('Y-m-d');
> the next :
>         if ($postjson['aksi']=='add')
>         {
>             $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO master_customer SET
>             name_customer = '$postjson[name_customer]',
>             desc_customer = '$postjson[desc_customer]',
>             created_at = '$today'
>             ");   
>
>             $idcust = msqli_insert_id($mysqli);
>
>             if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'customerid'=> $idcust));
>             else $result = json_encode(array('succes'=>false));
>
>             echo $result;
>
> *elseif ($postjson['aksi']=='update'){
>     $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE master_customer SET
>     name_customer='$postjson[name_customer]',
>     desc_customer='$postjson[desc_customer]' WHERE customer_id='$postjson[customer_id]'");*
> ```

```
 **it is said the error was here --->**   

if($query) $result = json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'result'=>$data));
        else $result = json_encode(array('success'=>false));

        echo $result;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where do you have that error ?

Comment: it said on json.parse right in the proses.api.php

Comment: but, as I've checked it is corret

Comment: Upload full code please and show us where do you have that error

Comment: done, please check it out on the question for about th end of it. Thank you

Comment: Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Find out what the "JSON data" (which is probably an HTML page) actually looks like.